# Can sending a Content-Length header greater than the actual content hang the copy operations in Golang?

Tags: http, go

The following code hangs the curl client and the read operation when the `Content-Length` header is greater than the actual content itself.

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "net/http"
)

func main() {
    err := http.ListenAndServe("localhost:8080", http.HandlerFunc(func(writer http.ResponseWriter, request *http.Request) {
        defer request.Body.Close()
        fmt.Println("Body:")
        bb := make([]byte, 1)
        for {
            n, err := request.Body.Read(bb) //code hangs here after reading 2 bytes, because Read does not return
            if err == io.EOF {
                break
            }
            if err != nil {
                fmt.Println("Error reading:", err.Error())
                break
            }
            fmt.Printf("Read %d bytes => %q\n", n, bb)
        }
        fmt.Println("Copied")
        _, _ = fmt.Fprintln(writer, "hello")
    }))
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

}
```

Curl call

```bash
curl -vv -d '{}' -H 'Content-Length:3' localhost:8080
```

If the actual `Content-Length:2` is specified, the code works fine. When `Content-Length` is less than or equal to the actual `Content-Length` the code works as exepcted, but if it is greater than it then I cannot read the body

Comment: The server is expecting to read more bytes from the open connection.  The server will wait for those bytes until the connection is closed.

Comment: This could be a potential DDOS attack right? This can cause a lot of file descriptors to be used up

Comment: For DDOS, Content-Length is irrelevant.  All clients have to do to cause a DDOS is make an HTTP request and then not read the body.  Or on a request with client content body such as POST, make a request and not write a request body.

Comment: Yes, this is how the HTTP protocol works. If the client says it will send 3 bytes, and only sends 2,  the serve should wait some period of time for that last byte to arrive. It's not just Go, all HTTP servers will adhere to the HTTP protocol.

Comment: A robust application will use the [Server](https://pkg.go.dev/net/http#Server) timeout options to mitigate denial of service attacks.